# Nativescript - build error under Android

Tags: nativescript

Getting the following error when doing a production build on the Android.

Debug build works - but web-packing is disabled.

I've get web-packing enabled.

The build script was working before I upgraded to 3.4 - something changed?

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/asrock/Documents/publish-android/platforms/android/build-tools/android-static-binding-generator/build.gradle' line: 281
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':asbg:generateBindings'.

  > No /Users/asrock/Documents/publish-android/platforms/android/build-tools/android-static-binding-generator/bindings.txt was found after runAstParser task was ran! Check to see if there are any .js files inside /Users/asrock/Documents/publish-android/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app`

Comment: In the folder /assets/app - there is NO .js files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, resolved with upgrade:

Component nativescript has 4.0.0 version and is up to date.

Component tns-core-modules has 4.0.0 version and is up to date.

Component tns-android has 4.0.0 version and is up to date.

Component tns-ios has 4.0.1 version and is up to date.

nativescript-angular              │ 5.3.0   │